# C# Determing HTML Link Given Website

Tags: c#

If I am at a given website, with a given full URL, how can I determine the absolute path of any href or src attribute.

So if I have:

```
string WebsiteImAt = "http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp?q=1&s=2,2#a"
//Just some random website with a sub path and a filename

string text = DownloadHTML(WebsiteImAt);

string href = "/something/somethingelse/filename.asp";
//Should go to http://www.w3schools.com/something/somethingelse/filename.asp

string href2 = "something.asp";
//Should go to http://www.w3schools.com/media/something.asp

string href3 = "something";
//Should go to http://www.w3schools.com/media/something
```

I'm having trouble getting my regex to work with "/blah" and just "blah" without the slashes:

```
String value = Regex.Replace(text, "<(.*?)(src|href)=\"(?!http)(.*?)\"(.*?)>", "<$1$2=\"" + absoluteUrl + "$3\"$4>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

return value.Replace(WebsiteImAt + "/", WebsiteImAt);
```

I cannot alter each href/src to resolve to the correct address.  How do I fix my regex to account for the three href cases above?